# Url to access a website proxied by Cloudflare without hostname and without /etc/hosts or a custom ᴅɴꜱ server?

Tags: browser, reverse-proxy

https://wex1.in is a website which scammed more than 1 million users mostly in Russia (but had no problem with users between 2011‒2017 so many peoples like me ended up trusting them).
The current status is only the domain name was deleted so that the website is still reachable by adding `104.25.31.35 wex1.in` to etc/hosts files (but logging in is disabled).

The website uses Cloudflare. For having delt with such issues in the past, I know Cloudflare have no problem at revealing quickly the underlying hosting provider country’s of a website through an abuse report at their [abuse form](https://www.cloudflare.com/abuse/form) without any legal requirements.

The problem is [the form automatically detects](https://www.cloudflare.com/abuse/form) https://wex1.in does no longer resolve and refuse to allow submitting.
And of course, `104.25.31.35` is not unique to World Exchange Service so that https://[104.25.31.35]:443 doesn’t works since the ʜᴛᴛᴘ host header isn’t set to `wex1.in`.

So is there a way to access a part of wex1.in only through crafting the ᴜʀʟ syntax in the web‑browser on the ᴘᴄ without a thrid party extension ? Any type of ᴜʀʟ is accepted by https://www.cloudflare.com/abuse/form

Comment: **This sounds like a website question but boils down to a technical web‑browser question for setting the ʜᴛᴛᴘ host header to the proper name in reality**. And this isn’t because your bank pays billions in fines for allowing peoples to launder money that you are a criminal/money launderer yourself (Wold Exchange Service was one of the first cheap way to withdraw money to the Western Wold from Russia or to simply exchange fiat currencies).

Comment: Send them an email. Abuse Contact Email: `registrar-abuse@cloudflare.com` or `abuse@Cloudflare.com` for an alternative.

Comment: @DavidPostill I would say the peoples here are tasked to work/behave like bots (through following a script described at alghorithm level) despite being humans. I tried and I simply got the reply from them that https://wex1.in is no longer at CloudFlare since wex1.in does no longer resolves (not paying attention to the /etc/hosts explaination). **So things which don’t pass on the automated form won’t be handled manually either**. Justice would take month to handle this which makes the site would had likely been shut down by the time.